# Unique variable for each run of a thread

Tags: jmeter, automated-tests, load-testing

I've got a jmeter script to test a user journey through a number of forms.

Ideally the email address for each journey would be unique but it's proven difficult to achieve this.

I have a user defined variable for email;

```
${__V(${__UUID()}${__RandomString(20,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,)}_jmeter@my-co.com)}
```

Then a BeanShell PreProcessor to create a uniqueID;

```
int threadNo = ctx.getThreadNum()+1; //to get the thread number in beanshell
int base = 35000;
int uniqueId = threadNo + base;
vars.put("uniqueId", Integer.toString(uniqueId));
```

Finally, in the POST data I've been defining;

```
_${__threadNum}.${uniqueId}.${Email}
```

However if I want to run a long test, the threads loop so I believe the thread number is the same, so the email doesn't change. Or at least the 403 errors seen during longer tests suggest that.

Can the loop count or some other identifier be used on the `uniqueId` or in the data for the POST perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

- [vars.getIteration()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#getIteration()) - to get current loop number (on [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level)
- [Counter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) element or even better [${__counter(FALSE,)}](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) function which will generate incremented number each time being called. See [How to Use a Counter in a JMeter Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-counter-jmeter-test) for details.

However [HTTP Status Code 403](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.4.4) stands for "Forbidden"

> The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
> Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated.
> If the request method was not HEAD and the server wishes to make
> public why the request has not been fulfilled, it SHOULD describe the
> reason for the refusal in the entity.  If the server does not wish to
> make this information available to the client, the status code 404
> (Not Found) can be used instead.

so your problem seems to be connected with something else

Comment: Thank you. The 403 looks to be caused by one of our systems flagging the email address as already in use. So I'm not too worried about that, it should go away if I can include the iteration in the variables I hope.